# Solidity standard library: how to contribute?

Tags: solidity, solc

I'd like to contribute to Solidity standard library, which seems a bit feature-less. How can I do that? Is there are some agreements about Solidity standard lib like in c++?

I have implemented some functions that are probably useful in Smart Contracts: https://github.com/alianse777/solidity-standard-library

Comment: You might want to ask this question in the [Solidity Matrix server](https://matrix.to/#/%23ethereum_solidity:gitter.im).

Answer (score 0):

I found some useful links in Solidity documentation.

[Article about the contribution](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contributing.html).

[Coding standards](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/develop/CodingStandards.txt).

Comment: Thanks, but this is coding standards, not a standard library specifications.

Comment: @Alianse777 my bad. I haven’t found what you were asking for, but I found [this repo](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/tree/develop/std) in official solidity on github which is called standard. It is pretty small and considering its size I can assume there are no special agreements yet.

Comment: @Alianse777 by the way I’ve stared your repo and will test out your lib. Thanks for a good work and I hope you will successfully contribute to solidity.